# Delete folders from the publish output on an ASP.NET Core 1.1 project

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 project with the following in the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />   
  <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />       
</ItemGroup>
```

One of the Nuget packages included in the project adds a few localization folders to the publish output, e.g.: 'en', 'pt', 'fr', ...

I need to delete theses folders from the publish folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to use one or more None elements using the Exclude attribute, e.g. `<None Exclude="en\**\*;pt\**\*;fr\**\*"/>` You may also be able to use a Folder element and the Exclude element, e.g. `Folder Exclude="en; pt;fr"/>`.

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items)